# JavaScript - Pushing JSON Object Using Value as Element Name

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to push an object inside an array with dynamic attribute name.

Let's say we have the following variables defined

```
myJSON = {"students" : [ {"name":"Your Name"}, {"name":"My Name"} ] };

attribName = "name";

myValue = "myValue";

parsedJSON = JSON.parse(myJSON);

parsedJSON["students"].push({attribName : myValue});

myJSON = JSON.stringfy(parsedJSON);
```

The example isn't working. Is there a way to push an object with dynamic attribute name?

Comment: This is not a question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From *MDN*,

> *An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the [**square bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties). This notation is also very useful when property names are to be dynamically determined (when the property name is not determined until runtime).*

Also note that input you has provided is `object`, not `json`

```js
var myJSON = {
  "students": [{
    "name": "Your Name"
  }, {
    "name": "My Name"
  }]
};

var attribName = "name";

var myValue = "myValue";

var obj = {};
obj[attribName] = myValue;
myJSON["students"].push(obj);
console.log(myJSON);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function(key, value, json) {

  var obj = {};
  obj[key] = value;
  json['students'].push(obj);

  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the modification in your code :

```
 myJSON = {"students" : [ {"name":"Your Name"}, {"name":"My Name"} ] };

attribName = "name";

myValue = "myValue123";

myJSON["students"].push({attribName: myValue});

console.log(myJSON);
```